# js / dataTable plug-in / table th, td width ratio problem

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, datatables

I use 'dataTables - plug-in' in my project.

I use 'colgroup' for td width.

but, The certain td has too long text.
So, It makes the problem. th width , td width are different.

How can I manage td width, th width ?

Oh. if there is a scroll-bar option, there are two tables in dataTables.

One is for th.
Another is for tbody.

I tested in url 'https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/scroll_xy.html'.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a [mre] in the question?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is the expected behavior for any cell in a table. Many different ways to address this. To be able to help, please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example